# Time complexity for adding elements to list vs set in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does adding elements to a set take longer than adding elements to a list in python? I created a loop and iterated over 1000000 elements added it to a list and a set. List is consistently taking around 10 seconds vs set which is taking around 20 seconds.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both operations are *O(1) [amortized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis)* time-complexity.

Appending elements to a list has a lower coefficient because it does not need to hash the element first, nor does it need to check/handle hash collisions.

In the case of adding `x` into a `set`, Python needs to compute `hash(x)` first, because keeping the hash of all elements is what allows sets to have fast *O(1)* membership checks (compared to *O(n)* membership checks for lists).

Comment: Thanks @wim , so in case of set , the value of constant is higher ?

Comment: Yes. It's slower in absolute, but it's not becoming any slower depending on the size of the set/list.

Comment: Not just `hash(x)` - it also may have to test `arr[i] == x` several times when there is a hash collision.

Comment: Does adding involve o(log n) check to see if item already exists in the set before performing the insertion?

Comment: No. This is O(1) amortized.

Comment: No, testing membership of a hashtable is O(1), not O(log n) - and the membership test is done while probing for the index to insert at anyway.

Comment: What is done as part of probing the index and how is it O(1)?

Comment: The hash will tell where in memory to populate an element, if that place is already filled by an unequal object then you have a deterministic "perturbation" algorithm telling you how to find some other index to use instead. The storage will resize itself dynamically so that usually only have to probe 0 or 1 times, regardless of the size of the set. This is how you can get *O(1)* on average, but sometimes it will be significantly slower when there is need to reallocate storage (that last part is true for both set and list, by the way).

Answer (score 8):

The time complexity for appending to a list is the same as for adding to a set - both are O(1) amortised operations, meaning on average they each take a constant amount of time, although occasionally the operation may take more than that constant amount of time in order to dynamically resize the array that the data is stored in.

However, just because both are O(1) doesn't mean they take the same amount of time:

- Appending to a list should be faster, because a list is implemented as a [dynamic array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array), so appending an element just requires writing that element at the right index (which is already known), and increasing the length by 1.
- In contrast, adding to a set is slower, because it requires computing the [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) of the element to find the index to start looking from, then [testing indices in some sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing) to see if the element is already there (by testing if there is an element at the index, and if so, whether it equals the element being inserted) until either finding it, or finding an empty space where the element should be added.

Comment: *"then testing each element from that index onwards"*  <-- this is not correct, Python does not use linear probing.

Comment: @wim You're right, I misremembered this detail, so thanks for the correction. Wikipedia doesn't seem to have an article on the particular scheme Python does use so I've replaced the link with a generic one.