# What is the difference between hashSet.add(n) and myList.append(n) in terms of Time Complexity?

Tags: python, time-complexity, hashset

Starting to leetcode and get Time Exceed Limit error.

Here is the function:

```
def containsDuplicate(nums: list[int]) -> bool:
    tempset = []
    for n in nums:
        if n in tempset:
            return True
        else:
            tempset.append(n)
    return False
```

When I just use an array(list), it gives the error. If tempset is a set(), it does not.
What is the difference between time complexities of the two operations? Shouldnt they both run in constant time? Or the problem is with `n in tempset` and how it calculates it behind the scene?

Comment: No they shouldn't both run in constant time. Finding an item in a list is _linear_ - https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

Comment: `a in x` in the average case is O(N) if `x` is a list, O(1) if `x` is a set.

Comment: Lists aren't arrays, btw. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: You get `Time Limit Exceeded Error(TLE)` for lists and not for sets because finding an element in a list is `O(N)` while find an element in a set is `O(1)`. Appending an element to a `list` and adding an element to a `set` both are `constant amortized O(1)`. Please see this answer of appending/adding element to a list/set...... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58792963/time-complexity-for-adding-elements-to-list-vs-set-in-python

Comment: Using a list: O(n^2) time complexity (due to the n in tempset operation on a list). Using a set: O(n) time complexity. For larger inputs, an O(n^2) algorithm will easily hit the time limit, which is why you're seeing a Time Limit Exceeded error when using a list. Using a set avoids this problem due to its more favorable time complexity for membership tests and additions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the line- `if n in tempset:`

When tempset is a list, the above line of code takes O(n) to execute as it iterates over each index to perform the check.

When tempset is a set, the above line of code takes O(1) to execute. Sets are implemented as hash tables, and they use a hash function to quickly locate the element in the set, making membership tests very efficient.